# Webworks: How to Run a Repeated Task

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I need to have a background process be started as soon as the blackberry is turned on and remain in the background. Here it will repeatedly run a function, say every half hour or so. Is this possible with the webworks API? I've been looking at blackberry events from https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.app.event.html but I have no idea if this is the right thing to use. I'm very new to this so I'm having trouble doing this part of my app. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a special page just for the background app, then set that to startup using a [special element in your configuration document](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_developing/rim_background_element_1265316_11.html) like this:

```
<content>
  <rim:background src="listener.html" runOnStartup="true" />
</content>
```

In that file you can run your code to use [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) in a loop to call your function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works though but you may try this idea: See https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.app.html. You can probably use requestBackground() as soon as the app starts. You also need to edit "entry points" section of config.xml file so that the app gets started at system startup.